# tailwindcss not using unprefixed utilities

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to get the height of the div to h-2 and on medium is set a class with height animation.

The problem is that tailwindcss still uses the h-20 on mobile while h-2 should be used.

any idea why ?

here is the div in question :

```
  <div className={`h-2 md:flex w-full text-white fixed bg-white mt-1 ${scrolling ? 'md:animationNav h-16' : 'md:animationBasisNav h-20'} dark:bg-gray-400`}></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that tailwindcss still uses the h-20 on mobile while h-2 should be used.

That's because you are using the class `h-20` (applies the 20 height in all screen sizes) instead of `md:h-20` (applies the 20 height in screen size `md` and upwards).

Similarly, you might want to change `h-16` to `md:h-16`.

You need to apply the `md:` prefix to all classes that you want to apply only in screen size `md` and upwards. Similarly for all other breakpoint prefixes. All classes are mobile-first by default (and "by default" means the absence of a breakpoint prefix). See the [*Responsive Design* section on Tailwind CSS docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design).

Comment: I understand that but the fact that I added a md: after the h-2 should apply all classes after it only to md right? or do i need to add md: to every class

Comment: Yep, you need to add it to all classes. I updated my answer.

Comment: that works, really sad that you cannot just add one time md and get all what is behind added to it, its avoid writing md on every class

Comment: You might be interested in [twin.macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro). I haven't used it personally, but it looks interesting. It provides some extra features to Tailwind, including applying variants (like breakpoint prefixes) to multiple classes at once.

Answer (score 1):

### My solution

Hey, maybe you want to try with this:

```html
  <div className={`h-2 md:flex w-full text-white fixed bg-white mt-1 ${scrolling ? 'md:animationNav md:h-16' : 'md:animationBasisNav md:h-20'} dark:bg-gray-400`}></div>
```

Now you are defining that the default height is 2, while in medium devices is 20.

Use this pattern in all your classes.

**First:** Define the height in mobile

**Second:** Add the classes for larger screen sizes.